# How to re-enable syntax highlighting of code that have been disabled by #if preprocessor statements

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cc-mode

Code between `#if SYMBOL` and `#endif` is greyed out in `cc-mode` if the `SYMBOL` has not been defined within the current file.

The project that I´m currently working on has a common code base for Mac and Windows so there´s a lot of `#if WINDOWS` and `#if MAC` in there. This results in lots of code in the editor that is grey and without syntax highlighting since these symbols are defined in some other compilation unit.

How can I enable syntax colouring in the current editor without editing the file? I can always add a `#define SYMBOL 1` above the `#if SYMBOL` but this does not feel right?

Comment: I don't think cc-mode does this by default. Are you using `hide-ifdef-mode` by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

It was emacs-cquery that shadowed code inside #if false regions. Setting cquery-enable-inactive-region to nil solved it.